# composer install issues

Tags: php, curl, composer-php, command-line-interface, mcrypt

When i'm trying to install composer
i got following error.Actually all modules are installed.

As per my knowledge  there will be two configuration files(apache2 & cli).

in both of the configuration files modules are enabled.still I'm facing this issue.

```
Problem 1
    - The requested PHP extension ext-gd * is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - The requested PHP extension ext-mcrypt * is missing from your system.
  Problem 3
    - The requested PHP extension ext-curl * is missing from your system.
  Problem 4
    - The requested PHP extension ext-intl * is missing from your system.
  Problem 5
    - The requested PHP extension ext-xsl * is missing from your system.
  Problem 6
    - The requested PHP extension ext-mbstring * is missing from your system.
  Problem 7
    - Installation request for braintree/braintree_php 2.39.0 -> satisfiable by braintree/braintree_php[2.39.0].
    - braintree/braintree_php 2.39.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
  Problem 8
    - Installation request for pelago/emogrifier v0.1.1 -> satisfiable by pelago/emogrifier[v0.1.1].
    - pelago/emogrifier v0.1.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
```

when i'm trying to update/install

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php5-curl is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.13.0-46 linux-headers-3.13.0-46-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-46-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-46-generic
  sendmail-base sendmail-cf sensible-mda
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 54 not upgraded.
```

**update:**
php -v

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20121212/php_mbstring.dll' - /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20121212/php_mbstring.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20121212/php_mbstring.dll' - /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20121212/php_mbstring.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.5.9 (cli) (built: Sep  8 2015 18:01:37) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

Comment: May seem like a dumb question but did you check if you enabled the extensions in your php.ini?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `php -m` to make sure the modules have been enabled in your php installation.

If they are not in the list, you will have to add them in your php.ini.

Comment: modules are not listed .i enabled in php.ini also

Comment: Are you sure you edited the correct php.ini? It is possible that you have more then one php.ini or more php versions on your server.

Comment: how to check how many php.ini files and paths.can you give some idea?

Comment: Can you add the output of `php -v` to your question and show us how you added the extensions in your php.ini?